# Laravel view passed value not capturing Undefined variable: val1

Tags: php, laravel, view

I have my controller and via that I am calling a new view which is a blade too.

```
 $var1="value1";
 $var2="value2";
 //return view('viewcall2', compact('var1','var2''));*/
 $data = array('var1'=>$var1, 'var2'=>$var2);
 return view('viewcall2')->with($data);
```

In the blade I call this.But I am getting this error Undefined variable: val1

```
<div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('VType', 'V Type', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                 <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label for="price">{{ $val1 }}</label>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Use `$var1` instead of `$val1`. Because you are passing key as `var1` in `$data = array('var1'=>$var1, 'var2'=>$var2);`.

Comment: @manwal thank you I just notice my mistake doing it did not notice it . Thank you maybe you can add as answer for other to benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

controller

```
return view('viewcall2')->with(compact($data));
```

view

```
  <label for="price">{{ $data['var1'] }}</label>
```

Comment: Is this the right way cause some say just {{ $var1' }} but say {{ $data['var1'] }} which is correct ?

Comment: Here I have used compact function

Comment: so for compact I must {{ $data['var1'] }}